# How to pull a User Variable from the database and display it in html/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, session

In my database I've created a table called accounts.
The accounts table contains: id, username, password, points.

This is the code I'm running to pull and display the Points variable.

```
$user = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM accounts WHERE username='".$user."'");
$points = $sql;
```

Then a bit further down I use this in html.

```
<p>Welkom, <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>! Dit is jouw Managerpaneel. Je hebt momenteel <?=$points?> Managerpunten.</p>
```

Now, it does show the session Username, but it doesn't display anything for points :( it just completely skips it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually fetching your results. `mysql_query()` returns a resource ID. You need to pass this to a function like `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get your actual results.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM accounts WHERE username='".$user."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$points = $row['points'];
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Right now I'm getting this.    Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\member.php on line 6

Comment: It looks correct. Try using mysql_error() to see what mysql says.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$points = $row['points'];
```

for more info: [**mysqlfetcharray**](http://pk1.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)